# Copying in large dataset using copy_from, using temp table to do ON CONFLICT, CardinalityViolation?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a table with emails and names, and the email column is unique. I followed someone's post on here that explained how to do a copy_from when you are dealing with a unique column. The process is A) create a temp table based on the table you are inserting the data, B) copy in the data from the file into the temp table, and C) copy the temp table to the main table with an ON CONFLICT statement to deal with uniques. See code below. For some reason, this is resulting in the error: `psycopg2.errors.CardinalityViolation: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.`

What could be causing this to happen? I would have thought a temp table with no constraints which is then copied to a main table with constraints (using ON CONFLICT) would work without a problem... and sometimes it does seem to work, it seems only certain files cause issues.

```
with connection.cursor() as stmt:
            stmt.execute('CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_main AS SELECT * FROM main WHERE 0 = 1') 
        
            with open(file) as f:
                stmt.copy_from(f, 'tmp_main', columns=('email','name'), sep=',')

            stmt.execute(f'INSERT INTO main (email,name) SELECT email,name FROM tmp_main ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET name = coalesce(excluded.name,main.name)') 
            stmt.execute('DROP TABLE tmp_main')
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put the data from the `main` table into `tmp_main`, you're just supposed to copy the table *structure*. What line is the error occurring at? It seems to me it would be triggered on the `stmt.copy_from()` line.

Comment: It's triggered on the `stmt.execute(f'INSERT INTO main (email,name) SELECT email,name FROM tmp_main ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET name = coalesce(excluded.name,main.name)')` line. Also I realized I meant to put `WHERE 0 = 1` at the end of the first statement. But it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `tmp_main` contains several rows with the same `email`. You will have to eliminate duplicates *before* you run `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. That means for you to figure out which of the rows with the same `email` should take effect.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) is quite clear about that:

> `INSERT` with an `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause is a “deterministic” statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error will be raised when this situation arises. Rows proposed for insertion should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by an arbiter index or constraint.

Comment: I’m confused - the point of making the temp table is to have all emails, including duplicates, and then transfer it to the main table with the on conflict so the duplicates get merged... That’s what confuses me about this whole thing.

Comment: Shouldn’t it merge the first row and then the second row (so, the second row is what ends up being used)? If I can’t do this, how do I do a copy_from and manage conflicts with unique email?

Comment: Sorry, still extremely confused. Take temp tables out of it for a second. You are saying I can't add two rows with the same email address using ON CONFLICT? Isn't that *exactly* what on conflict is used for? Could you provide an example of two rows that can't be inserted just in case I'm misunderstanding? Thanks!!

Comment: You can "add" two rows with the same `email` if you do it in different `INSERT` statements. What does not work is adding them with *a single* statement.

Comment: I added a link to the documentation.